# wcf service working with 'GET' and 500 error with 'POST'

Tags: wcf

I have a wcf service that it's working well if i am using get but 
when i use post it's showing

```
System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException status 500
```

any ideas whats the error??

here is the code

```
function Login(e) { 
debugger; 
e.preventDefault();
//getting mail 

var loginmail = 
$("[id$='txtLoginEmail']").val(); 

//getting password

var loginpassword = 
$("[id$='txtLoginPassword']").val(); 

//getting remember me checkbox

var checked = 
($("[id$='chkRememberme']").is(':checked')); 


var proxy = new _AppProxy('MemberService/Login', '', 'xml', 'POST', '', { mail: loginmail, password: 
loginpassword, rememberMe: checked }); 

proxy.Invoke();

};


[OperationContract] 
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = 
WebMessageFormat.Xml,Method="POST")] 

public string Login(string mail , string password , 
bool rememberMe) 
{

}

<system.serviceModel> 

<standardEndpoints> 

<webHttpEndpoint> 

<standardEndpoint 
name="" 
helpEnabled="true" 
automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" /> 

</webHttpEndpoint> 
</standardEndpoints>  
serviceHostingEnvironment 
aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" > 

</serviceHostingEnvironment> 

</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Please post the exception's message and call stack

Answer (score 1):

Can be that you miss the .svc ending in your URI to the WebService. If MemberService is the name of the service and Login is the name of the Method,

`MemberService.svc/Login`